# Confusion with writing query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I just have a simple doubt in cakephp, it may be also silly.

Writing queries in cakephp:-

```
1.$output1 = $this->Modelname->query("Select * from tablename");
2.$output2 = $this->Modelname->query("Update tablename set .....");
```

When i execute the first query i.e $output1. It runs perfectly.
But wen i run $output2 it wont run correctly

What may be the problem ??

Comment: This is not CakePHP. You usually never have to use query(), always try to use find()/save() etc as documented: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: "it won't run correctly" ....??  Have to be more specific here - also, it's impossible for us to guess at the end of your query - please supply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [CakePHP methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) to query against the database.

This way, it will be much more secure and things will be easier for you, more even if you have related models.

At first it can take a while to learn, but you will soon realize the advantages of it.

Your first query would be equivalent to:

```
$this->Modelname->find("all");
```

And your second one to something like:

```
// Update: id is set to a numerical value
$this->Modelname->id = 2; 
$this->Modelname->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the way to do this in CakePHP. The second example can be even more simple; if `$this->request->data` contains the ID, then only `Model->save(.....)` is required

Comment: Yes, following conventions, the id of the model name is usually supplied as a hidden element in the form so you can just pass the post data directly to the save method.

Setting the model->id would be more useful with something like:
Model::saveField or Model::field.

`<?php $this->ModelName->id = <#>; $this->ModelName->saveField('<field>', '<value'); $this->ModelName->field('<field>'); ?>`

or even `$this->ModelName->read()`

Comment: Using these as a sort of shorthand way, since if you didn't set the id on the model, for one, saveField, it's required, the others, you would have to supply the id either as a parameter, or as a conditions array.